# PHP Form submit get return value to html

Tags: javascript, php, html

My First page is contact.html page where i'm submitting the value using post method to contact.php file

html code for contact.html

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="textreply">
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

php code contact.php

```
<?php
if($_POST){
if(isset($_POST['textreply'])){
   $value = $_POST['textreply'];
   return $value;
 }
else{
   $value = "invalid data came from input box";
   return $value;
  }
}
```

i need to get the contact.php return value to the contact.html to display inside the contact.html page after submitting.

Please let me know if more details required.

Comment: An easier way would be to have the HTML and the form-handling code all inside contact.php, and then have contact.php post back to itself. That way if there are errors you can simply echo them into the page which is returned, which will include the form again. That is quite a standard pattern.

Comment: Or you can use AJAX to submit the form instead, which means your browser can stay within contact.html, and just get a success/failure response (and any error messages) from the PHP, and display it on screen.

Comment: Hi @ADyson thanks for the details. I have created a way getting url parameters once the php successfully sending the header of same page with parameters. After getting that parameter using javascript will show popup.